# the point to which everyone would have the shortest distance

Tags: real-analysis

Is there a mathematical way to calculate where is the point so that 5 people have the minimum distance(in straight line) from other points(their houses) to that one point ?I can pick "starting point"  that I know the distance of each person to it. That might be good point to start with, and correct it in iterative process ? I think it might be something simmilar to find the minimum or maximum of the funcion but wayy more complicated, but i have no idea how to create a equation or smth. Any help appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "minimum"? If $d_1, d_2, \ldots, d_5$ are the five distances, are you looking to minimize (1) the total distance $d_1 + d_2 + \ldots + d_5$, (2) the maximum distance $\max(d_1, d_2, \cdots, d_5)$, (3) the RMS of distances $\sqrt{(d_1)^2 + \cdots + (d_5)^2}$, (4) or are you looking for a optimum point where you cannot shorten the distance to any particular house without making the distance to someone else longer? Different formulations have different answers.

Comment: thats interesting, tbh im interested in option (1), and (4), but even if i know distances, how to put them on map with coordinates to find this special point

Comment: moreover, as i mentioned, i know the distance of each person to the starting point,

Comment: Note that option (2) can be solved very efficiently: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallest-circle_problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Total Distance version

Let $\vec{x}_1, \ldots, \vec{x}_5$ be the coordinates of the 5 houses, your goal is to minimize the function
$$ f(\vec{y}) = |\vec{y} - \vec{x}_1| + \cdots + |\vec{y} - \vec{x}_5| $$
The "calculus idea" would be to take the gradient and find the point $\vec{y}$ such that
$$ \nabla f = \frac{\vec{y} - \vec{x}_1}{|\vec{y} - \vec{x}_1|} + \cdots + \frac{\vec{y} - \vec{x}_5}{|\vec{y} - \vec{x}_5|} = 0$$
This however can get you into trouble: the function $f$ is not differentiable at any of the five locations, and if one of the 5 people happens to live at the optimum location, then calculus itself will not find the answer. So you will have to couple that to checking the 5 points individually to see if they are the minimum.

#### Algorithmically Speaking

Since you asked about a iterative procedure, and the cost $f$ is by definition a *convex* function, you can guarantee convergence with gradient descent.

```
Start with a random choice $y$. 

Make sure y is not one of the 5 houses, in which case change y randomly a little bit away from the choice. 
Use the formula for $\nabla f$ above to compute the vector $z = \nabla f(y)$. 
Replace $y$ by $y + \frac16 \nabla z$. 
Repeat the procedure.
```

The 1/6 factor is chosen to avoid over-shooting, since we have 5 houses we know that $|\nabla f| \leq 5 < 6$.

### Pareto Optimum version

The other option you mentioned is both a bit easier and a bit harder. The harder part is that gradient descent cannot be used, since you are no longer minimizing an objective function. And there's also the conceptual problem where that in this case there may be multiple solutions!

To see this, notice that if you have 3 houses arranged in a triangle, then **any** point inside the triangle is a Pareto Optimum: you cannot move closer to any one house without making the distance to the other houses longer!

On the other hand, this also makes the solution easier: generalizing a bit, you see if you choose any point within the [convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) of the houses, you will find one such Pareto optimum. (This also means that this criterion is actually not very fair!)

---

*Edit*: here's an implementation of the Weiszfeld algorithm in the Julia programming language.

```
using LinearAlgebra

function Weis(y,x)
        z = x .- [y]
        ls = broadcast(norm, z)
        w = sum( x ./ ls) ./ sum(1 ./ ls)
        return w
end

houses = [[1,1],[2,2],[-1,2],[-4,3], [0,5]]

guess = [0,0]
nextiter = Weis(guess, houses)

while(norm(guess-nextiter) > 0.0000001)
        global guess = nextiter
        global nextiter = Weis(guess,houses)
        print(nextiter, "\n")
end

print(nextiter)
```

(The implementation is slightly incomplete: I didn't add checking for when the guess comes too close to one of the houses.)

Comment: What about connecting each house, and find the center of  that geometric figure ? Will the distance from a single house to the center be the same for each person ?

Comment: When you have more than 3 houses there is no good definition of the "center". In your case, imagine your five houses around in a cross configuration with one in the center (like the 5 dots on a standard 6-sided die). Certainly it cannot be the case that the distance from every house to the center is the same!

Comment: So the first option " calculus way", I have to take two equations since y=[x,y], and solve nonlinear equations in wolframalpha ?

Comment: But there is no guarantee of correct result like u said. I really don't know how to write a program in C language to do it in a iterative way. Will u be able to help me and send a program ?

Comment: The system of equations is generally not solvable in closed form (see Blitzer's answer). Computer algebra software may be able to solve it approximately by root finding algorithms, but that in the end is doing exactly the same thing as any algorithmic search for the minimum. The expression for the gradient however can be used as a good sanity check after you found a candidate solution.

Comment: okey so if i put equations like  for example (x-20)/|x-20| + ...+ (x-42)/|x-42|=0, and equation : (y-50)/|y-50|+...+(y-8)/|y-8|=0             (x,y)=(20,50) ..... (x,y)=(42,8) I may get a result

Comment: but that method might diverge sometimes ?

Comment: The formula 2up is incorrect. The absolute value is the length of the vector $\vec{y} - \vec{x}$, not the componentwise absolute value.

Answer (score 2):

The concept you want is called the Geometric median:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_median

From the Wikipedia page:
"Despite the geometric median's being an easy-to-understand concept, computing it poses a challenge. ...it has been shown that no explicit formula, nor an exact algorithm involving only arithmetic operations and kth roots, can exist in general for the geometric median. Therefore, only numerical or symbolic approximations to the solution of this problem are possible under this model of computation."

Comment: Ah yes! And Weiszfeld's algorithm is quite a bit sharper than the one I gave above: the 1/6 in my post is based on an overestimate.